# Como selecionar texto de campo TEdit no Delphi 10

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Estou com um problema bem básico e não descubro a causa... Preciso que o texto de dentro de um TEdit fique inteiro selecionado quando o campo receber foco. Nos tempos de Delphi 7 com VCL eu fazia apenas `TEdit(Sender).SelLength := Length(TEdit(Sender).Text)` no evento `OnEnter`. Agora com Delphi 10.2 e FireMonkey já tentei de várias maneiras diferentes, mas não funciona.

Exemplo:

```
procedure TfPrincipal.Edit1Enter(Sender: TObject);
begin
   TEdit(Sender).SetFocus;
   TEdit(Sender).SelStart  := 0; // Ja tentei mudar este valor
   TEdit(Sender).SelLength := Length(TEdit(Sender).Text); // Ja tentei mudar este valor também
end;
```

No Firemonkey funciona diferente?

Comment: Fiz o teste e realmente não funciona. veja a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Outra coisa definir para `SelLength` um valor maior do que o número de caracteres de `SelStart` para resulta na seleção de todos os caracteres de `SelStart` até o final do texto.

```
TEdit(Sender).SetFocus ; 
TEdit(Sender).SelStart  : = 0; 
TEdit(Sender).SelLength := Length(TEdit(Sender).Text)+1;
```

Comment: Fiz os testes no Delphi 10.1 Berlin e funcionou perfeito. Adicione um +1 no tamanho da Length.

Comment: outra coisa você pode retirar o `TEdit(Sender).SetFocus;` já que na entrada  do controle o mesmo já está com o foco.

Comment: Eduardo, você fez seus testes usando o evento `OnClick` ou `OnEnter` do TEdit? Pois no evento `OnEnter`, que é o evento que eu estou usando, não funciona. Então estou adaptando um pouquinho a mais de código e usando o `OnClick`. Já a propriedade `HideSelection` eu não encontrei no Delphi 10.2 Tokyo.

Comment: os dois  com o `OnClick` eu coloquei o `SetFocus` e no `OnEnter` sem o `SetFocus`.

Comment: Sei lá... muito estranho o que está ocorrendo aqui. Não funciona nem no Windows nem no Android com evento `OnEnter` (e não existe a propriedade HideSelection). Mas obrigado pela atenção

Comment: HideSelection eu me confundi ... é para vlc vou editar a resposta

Comment: Ah sim, para VCL funciona tudo OK.

Comment: Acabei de fazer o teste no android com o Botão é seleciona normal tanto no windows como no android  mais ao entra no campo só funciona no windows vou verificar

Comment: Acabei de testar com um evento Edit1Tap tanto o Edit1Enter eles funcionam o problema que percebi é que quando ele entra no Controle o foco vai embora provavelmente por conta do teclado virtual que entra na frente.

Comment: Essa parada é estranha... Mas não se preocupe. Vou usar o evento `OnClick`, adaptando algumas coisas. Não gosto de fazer isso, mas não dá para ficar gastando muita energia em determinadas coisas também. Obrigado!

Comment: marca como respontado se te ajudou...

Comment: só posso marcar como resposta válida se tiver sido resolvido o problema tal como foi proposto, que neste caso é no Firemonkey com evento `OnEnter` do TEdit. Sua dica não se aplica a este caso e tive que contornar o problema usando o evento `OnClick` como comentei antes. Mas obrigado!